# Changing aspectratio of scatter3d plot

Tags: r, plotly

Whenever I try to make a scatter3d plot using plotly, I get a square plot area (1x1x1).

Lets say I want a different aspect-ratio. Fixed to 1x1x2 or even data driven. How is this done?

I can read that this is supposed to be changed like this:

```
fig = plot_ly(df) %>%
add_trace(x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = "scatter3d", mode = "markers", size = 1) %>%
layout(aspectmode = "data")
```

However I get an error saying aspectmode is not an attribute of layout.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what about if you change layout to  layout(scene = list(aspectmode  = "manual", aspectratio = list(x=1,y=1,z=2)) 

This manual might be helpful https://plotly.com/r/reference/#layout-scene-aspectmode

Comment: This solved it. I believe i was simply missing the scene=list part. 
I am still getting used to plot_ly and not really familiar with all these list arguments yet. Trying to understand why they are needed. I am more experienced with ggplot..